# MySQL/Python LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE error

Tags: python, mysql

I am working with OSX 10.10.5 and MySQL 5.7.11 and trying to load txt data to mysql tables. My code was working until I add load_data function.

```
import pymysql as mdb
import os

def connect(user, password):
    return mdb.connect('localhost', user, password, local_infile=True)

def create_table(name):
    cursor.execute("""drop table if exists %s """ % (name))
    cursor.execute("""create table %s(try VARCHAR(4))""" %(name))

def load_data(file_name, table_name):
    load_data="""load data local infile "%s" into table %s""" % (file_name, table_name)
    cursor.execute(load_data)

con = connect('root','xxx')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("use mydb")

table_names = ['dbtry','dbtry1','dbtry2']
file_names = os.listdir("/usr/local/mysql/bin/try")
for i in range(0,3):
    create_table(table_names[i])
    load_data(file_names[i],table_names[i])

con.close()
```

Then the code gave this error:

```
ERROR 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

And it directed me to the:

```
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data-local.html
```

Then I found "my-default.cnf" in  "/usr/local/mysql/support-files" and copied it to "/etc". I added local-infile=1 under [mysqld]. When I asked MySQL:

```
 SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "local%";
```

it gave me:

```
 +---------------+-------+
 | Variable_name | Value |
 +---------------+-------+
 | local_infile  | ON    |
 +---------------+-------+
```

Finally, when I added local_infile=True to return of the connect function, it raised a new error:

```
File "/Volumes/RADYO/dbtry.py", line 26, in <module>
  load_data(file_names[i],table_names[i])
File "/Volumes/RADYO/dbtry.py", line 15, in load_data
  cursor.execute(load_data)
File "/Users/elf/Desktop/elif/mysql-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 158, in execute
  result = self._query(query)
File "/Users/elf/Desktop/elif/mysql-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 308, in _query
  conn.query(q)
File "/Users/elf/Desktop/elif/mysql-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 820, in query
  self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
File "/Users/elf/Desktop/elif/mysql-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1002, in _read_query_result
  result.read()
File "/Users/elf/Desktop/elif/mysql-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1290, in read
  self._read_load_local_packet(first_packet)
File "/Users/elf/Desktop/elif/mysql-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1326, in _read_load_local_packet
  sender.send_data()
File "/Users/elf/Desktop/elif/mysql-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1457, in send_data
  raise err.OperationalError(1017, "Can't find file '{0}'".format(self.filename))
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1017, "Can't find file 'try1.txt'")
```

But there is the file 'try1.txt' in the directory. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is likely in the pymysql client.  It looks like you should be able to do the following:

```
def connect(user, password):
    return mdb.connect('localhost', user, password,local_infile=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, something changed with adding this, but it is still not working. I edited the question for error @dfb

Comment: @elfxx - try using the full path

Comment: "/usr/local/mysql/bin/try" is my full path or  do you mean any other thing @dfb?

Comment: It's working by changing the path :) Thanks a lot @dfb !!

Comment: Thanks! @dfb worked like a charm. FYI: this parameter works with PyMySQL as well